# DropDown and TextBox logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic

I'm coding a Simple Dependable Logic

I have a DropDown list called "frequencyList"
which contains values like -
"Hourly", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"

I have Textbox called "frequencyCount"
which must accept only Digits.

Now the Logic I need is -
If user selects "Hourly" option from the DropDown 
The TextBox must only accept integer values between 1-23 else throw error,

**If user selects "Daily", TextBox to accept only between 1-30**, and so on

So here is my flawed logic so far, please correct me -

```
$("#frequencyCount").keypress(function(e) 
{
    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
    {
        console.log("Invalid Input, It's not Digits");
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Input is Digits for sure now
        if (frequecyList == "Daily") 
        {
            if (frequencyCount >= 1 && frequencyCount <= 30) 
            {
                console.log("Valid Daily input");
            } 
            else 
            {
                console.log("Invalid frequency");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will help you

```js
function validate() {
  var freq = $("#frequency").val();
  var num = $("#fvalue").val();
  var error = 0;

  if(freq==1 && (num <1 || num >23) ) {
    error = 1;     
  }
  else if(freq==2 && (num <1 || num > 30) ) {
    error = 1;
  }

  if(error==1)
  {
    alert("error");
    $("#fvalue").val('');
    $("#fvalue").focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="frequency">
  <option value="1">Hourly</option>
  <option value="2">Daily</option>
  <option value="3">Weekly</option>
  <option value="4">Monthly</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="fvalue" onblur="validate();" />
```